# Is a "solution" to a tensor product unique? Given $B, C$, is there a unique $A$ such that $A \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} B \simeq C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let's say that $B$ and $C$ are known $\mathbb{F}_2$-modules. We are given the following isomorphism:

$$A \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} B \simeq C$$

Can one prove that if such an $A$ exists, it is unique (up to isomorphism of $\mathbb{F}_2$-modules)?

Comment: A $\mathbb F_2$-module is a vector space right ? If $B,C$ are finite dimensional then $A$ is fully determined up to isomorphism. If $B,C$ are infinite dimensional, then $A$ is not unique up to iso.

Comment: Oh, excellent, thank you! That answers my question completely.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@N.H. You can make your comment  as an answer so that this post does not remain open. Also OP is satisfied with your answer.

Let me add my long  comment as answer.

This problem becomes interesting only for modules over rings, rather than for vector spaces. Let us take the subring of  $A\subset \mathbf{Q}$ consisting of numbers with odd denominators.  *Let us take all tensor products below as $\mathbf{Z}$-modules.* Let $B$ be the Klein's four-group (or any $\mathbf F_2$ vector space) and  $B_1,B_2$  finite abelian groups of odd order, all regarded as $\mathbf{Z}$-modules. Then one has (extension of scalars)
$$A\otimes (B\oplus B_1)\cong A\otimes (B\oplus B_2)$$
The above isomorphism is as $A$-modules. Hence also as abelian groups. 
So the uniqueness asked in the question  fails.

Comment: The question is about tensor products of vector spaces over a field ($\Bbb{F}_2$). So it's a bit odd to give an answer saying that the problem is not interesting for vector spaces,

Comment: @Rob Arthan: In the light of the answer By N.H. (posted as comment which I mentioned) readily accepted by OP what now remains is this. (That was my intention. Sorry if this sounded otherwise).